# Find Gap between dates ranges SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

l want to get the gap between dates range via SQL query lets see the situation:

l have table employees like : Every month the employee deserve payment

```
 ID  Name     From_date    To_date    Paid_Amount`

  1    ali     01/01/2002  31/01/2002    300
  2    ali     01/02/2002  28/02/2002    300
  3    ali     01/04/2002  30/04/2002    300
  4    ali     01/05/2002  31/05/2002    300
  5    ali     01/07/2002  31/07/2002    300
```

Now, we notice there are no payments in March and June
so, how by SQL query I can't get these months ??

Comment: Use a `dates` table with an `outer join`...

Comment: It must be only one months difference or it can be any ?

Comment: it can be more than one month

Comment: A very simple solution would be to check the number of days between the dates: `from_date - lag(to_date) over (partition by name order by to_date)`

Comment: i did not get it well ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
with mine(ID,Name,From_date,To_date,Paid_Amount) as
(
 select  1,'ali','01/01/2002','31/01/2002',300 from dual union all
 select  2,'ali','01/02/2002','28/02/2002',300 from dual union all
 select  3,'ali','01/04/2002','30/04/2002',300 from dual union all
 select  4,'ali','01/05/2002','31/05/2002',300 from dual union all
 select  5,'ali','01/07/2002','31/07/2002',300 from dual
 ),
 gtfirst (fromdt,todt) as (
       select min(to_Date(from_Date,'dd/mm/yyyy')) fromdt,max(to_Date(to_Date,'dd/mm/yyyy')) todt from mine
 ),
 dualtbl(first,last,fromdt,todt) as
 (
     select * from(select TRUNC(ADD_MONTHS(fromdt, rownum-1), 'MM') AS first,TRUNC(LAST_DAY(ADD_MONTHS(fromdt, rownum-1))) AS last,fromdt,todt from gtfirst connect by level <=12)
     where first between fromdt and todt and last between fromdt and todt
 )
select to_char(first,'month') no_payment_date from dualtbl where first not in (select to_Date(from_Date,'dd/mm/yyyy') from mine)
and first not in (select to_Date(to_date,'dd/mm/yyyy') from mine)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the date difference between one payment date and the previous payment date **and** the ID field is sequential, then you may simply join back to the table and select the previous row.

```
SELECT X.From_date, Y.From_date, Y.From_date - X.From_date Difference
FROM Employees X
LEFT OUTER JOIN Employees Y ON Y.ID = X.ID - 1
```

If the ID field is not sequential, then you can use a similar method, but build a temporary table with a row index that you can use to join back to the previous payment.